# Low water pressure at reverse osmosis tap after running fridge dispenser

Tags: water, water-pressure

I was replacing the air filter in my fridge and decided to install a water filter while I was at it ( *it came with the air filter* ).

I ran roughly 2 gallons of water through the dispenser after installation, as recommended by the manufacturer.

After doing so, the pressure at the fridge water dispenser was low, but so was the pressure at my reverse osmosis tap at the kitchen sink.

The sink is on the opposite wall from the fridge. I waited a bit and tried it again, and the same thing happened.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Are you on a well?

Comment: @HoneyDo No, not on a well. For the record I live in a PUD (planned unit development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse osmosis systems have a holding tank containing treated water. If you run it for an extended period and drain the holding tank the pressure will often drop until it's replenished. I'm guessing your refrigerator water is sourced from the RO system. If so, it should replenish but sometimes with slow flow systems it takes a while..

Comment: I didn't think it would be the case, but on closer inspection it seems you are right. There is a line tee'd off from the faucet line that routes somewhere under the floor, presumably to the fridge.